# Productivity tool to help me add multiple fields at once

Tags: 7, entities

Is there any Drupal productivity tool that will help me create multiple fields at the same time? I'm taking about about the actual creation of the fields under /admin/structure/types/manage/node_type/fields. I have a hundred of fields to create and it seems tedious to keep hitting the save button every time I create one.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering about the use case for hundreds of fields - this seems a bit bizarre. Maybe consider using [Field Collections](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) to group similar fields and combine with use multiple values per field on a field collection.

As for a possible solution (although not recommended since a lot of things could go wrong) - if you have many similar fields you could export some "base" fields using [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) and copy-paste inside the features' files the relevant fields. Clearing cache or feature-revert would create the relevant fields.

Comment: Not hundreds, just a hundred somewhere around 120. But they are spread across two node types. Yes a lot of them have the same field type, creating even just 20 fields at the same time would already ease my work.

Comment: So go with the copy-paste of features. It's a bit technical:
You'd have to make sure all the relevant things are copied and names match (in mymodule.features.field.inc and .info files for example)

Answer (score 1):

Another path that's different from Moo64c's good suggestion using the Features module, is to use the Drupal API to create the fields programmatically using [`field_create_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7) & [`field_create_instance()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7). Here's an [example tutorial](http://www.monarchdigital.com/blog/2013-08-09/programmatically-creating-fields-drupal-7). You can find many different examples over the web.